# type error on compilation with flex and bison

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I have to implement a parser of expression tree (like "(a > b) AND (c <= d)") using flex and bison, but I fails to solve type errors...

The fatal errors occur during the g++ compilation of the parser.y.c file (which is generated by this command : "bison -o parser.y.c -d parser.y") :

```
parser.y:54:36: erreur: request for member ‘nodeVal’ in ‘*(yyvsp + -8u)’, which is of pointer type ‘Node*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
parser.y:58:14: erreur: request for member ‘nodeVal’ in ‘yyval’, which is of pointer type ‘Node*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
parser.y:58:55: erreur: request for member ‘strVal’ in ‘*(yyvsp + -16u)’, which is of pointer type ‘Node*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
parser.y:58:82: erreur: request for member ‘strVal’ in ‘* yyvsp’, which is of pointer type ‘Node*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
parser.y:59:14: erreur: request for member ‘nodeVal’ in ‘yyval’, which is of pointer type ‘Node*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
parser.y:59:55: erreur: request for member ‘strVal’ in ‘*(yyvsp + -16u)’, which is of pointer type ‘Node*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)
```

There is also a warning that I don't understand :
parser.lex:35: warning, la règle ne peut être pairée [english : "rule cannot be matched"]

I hope someone can help me !

Here, the parser.y file :

```
%{

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

#include "Node.h"
#include "parser.lex.h"

#define YYSTYPE Node*

int yyerror(char *s) {
    printf("%s\n",s);
}

extern "C++"
{
    int yyparse(void);
    int yylex(void);
    Node * rootNode;
}

%}

%union {
    Node * nodeVal;
    char * strVal;
}

%token <strVal> IDENT
%token <strVal> LT GT LE GE EQ NE
%token <strVal> AND OR
%token <strVal> LEFT_PARENTHESIS RIGHT_PARENTHESIS
%token FIN

%left   LT GT LE GE EQ NE
%left   AND OR

%type<nodeVal> Expression

%start Input
%%

Input:
          /* Vide */
        | Input Ligne
        ;

Ligne:
          FIN
        | Expression FIN                { rootNode = $1; }
        ;

Expression:
          IDENT LT IDENT  { $$=new Node("<", $1, $3); }
        | IDENT GT IDENT  { $$=new Node(">", $1, $3); }
        | IDENT LE IDENT  { $$=new Node("<=", $1, $3); }
        | IDENT GE IDENT  { $$=new Node(">=", $1, $3); }
        | IDENT EQ IDENT  { $$=new Node("=", $1, $3); }
        | IDENT NE IDENT  { $$=new Node("!=", $1, $3); }
        | Expression AND Expression  { $$=new Node("AND", $1, $3); }
        | Expression OR Expression  { $$=new Node("OR", $1, $3); }
        | LEFT_PARENTHESIS Expression RIGHT_PARENTHESIS        { $$=$2; }
        ;

%%

void parse_string(const std::string & str)
{
    yy_scan_string(str.c_str());
    yyparse();
}
```

then the parser.lex file :

```
%{

#define YYSTYPE Node*

#include <cstdlib>

#include "BooleanNode.h"
#include "AttributeNode.h"
#include "parser.y.h"

extern "C++"
{
    int yylex(void);
}

%}

%option noyywrap

blancs          [ \t]+

ident           [a-zA-Z_]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9_]*

%%

{ident}         { return(IDENT); }

"<"    return(LT);
">"    return(GT);
"<="   return(LE);
">="   return(GE);
"="    return(EQ);
"!="   return(NE);

"AND"  return(AND);
"OR"   return(OR);

"("    return(LEFT_PARENTHESIS);
")"    return(RIGHT_PARENTHESIS);

"\n"  return(FIN);
```

and finally the Node.h file :

```
#ifndef _NODE_H_
#define _NODE_H_

#include <string>
#include <iostream>


class Node
{
public:

    enum E_op
    {
        AND = 0,
        OR,
        LT,
        GT,
        LE,
        GE,
        EQ,
        NE
    };

    Node(const std::string & op)
    {
        _op = op;
    }

    Node(const std::string & op, const std::string & left, const std::string & right)
    {
        _op = op;
    }

    Node(const std::string & op, Node * left, Node * right)
    {
        _op = op;
    }

    virtual ~Node()
    {

    }

    virtual void print() {}

protected:

    std::string _op;
};


#endif
```

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Jonathan Leffler and some others corrections (char* instead of std::string in %union), the compilation goes well but the result is not what I expected.
With the "foo < bar" expression, the "IDENT LT IDENT" directive is executed but the value of  $1 and $3 is NULL...

** NEW UPDATE **

I corrected the error by splitting the Expression directive :

```
Expression:
          id LT id  { $$ = new Node("<", $1, $3); }
        | id GT id  { $$ = new Node(">", $1, $3); }
        | id LE id  { $$ = new Node("<=", $1, $3); }
        | id GE id  { $$ = new Node(">=", $1, $3); }
        | id EQ id  { $$ = new Node("=", $1, $3); }
        | id NE id  { $$ = new Node("!=", $1, $3); }
        | Expression AND Expression  { $$ = new Node("AND", $1, $3); }
        | Expression OR Expression   { $$ = new Node("OR", $1, $3); }
        | LEFT_PARENTHESIS Expression RIGHT_PARENTHESIS   { $$ = $2; }
        ;

id:
          IDENT     { $$ = strdup(yytext); }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you've declared that the Yacc stack contains `Node *` elements via the `#define YYSTYPE Node *` define, but your `%union`, `%token` and `%type` declarations say that there are `StrVal` and `NodeVal` types within the union.

IIRC, you only use `YYSTYPE` when you do not use `%union`.  Removing that line should resolve the other problems.

Comment: Compilation OK, but I still have a problem (described in UPDATE section ) :(

Comment: Your constructors in `class Node` appear to ignore the operands and only record the operator; this could lead to the observed behaviour. Working out why you're seeing what you're seeing without the accurate code is going to be hard, very hard. Please look up how to provide an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: The node class shown above is minimalist, the real one is complete but the error still occur.
I found where the error comes, I will update the question.